# Equating coefficients of $ \sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{a_n}{n^s} = \sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{b_n}{n^s}, $

Tags: discrete-mathematics, complex-numbers, zeta-functions, riemann-hypothesis, gaussian-integers

Given that
$$
\sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{a_n}{n^s} = \sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{b_n}{n^s},
$$
for **all** complex values of $s$ and where $a_n$ and $b_n$  are non-negative integers, can we say that $a_n = b_n$ for all $n$?

Genesis of the question: While studying the basics of Gaussian integers, I came across such an equation in https://www.maths.nottingham.ac.uk/plp/pmzcw/download/fnt_chap5.pdf (page 7).

Ideas: Of course if you replace the denominators $\{1^s, 2^s, 3^s, \dots\}$ with variables $\{x_1, x_2, x_3,\dots\}$ or $\{x, x^2, x^3, \dots\}$ then, it will be true. But we cannot do that.

I don't think induction will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's true. $a_n$ and $b_n$ can be complex numbers and in fact you only need the identity to hold for $s$ in some open subset of $\mathbb{C}$, and maybe even less than that. But since you allow all $s$ (I will only need sufficiently large real $s$) we can simplify the argument as follows.

Take $s \to \infty$ to be real. The limit on each side is $a_1$ and $b_1$ respectively, so we get $a_1 = b_1$. Each term $n^{-s}$ vanishes exponentially faster than the previous term so the two sides grow as $a_1 + a_2 2^{-s} + O(3^{-s})$ resp. $b_1 + b_2 2^{-s} + O(3^{-s})$ and matching growth rates gives $a_2 = b_2$. Then we can continue matching up growth rates on each side term by term. (I am being sloppy here; we need to bound the $a_n$ and the $b_n$ using the fact that the Dirichlet series converges to do this more carefully.)

As an alternative argument you can use [Perron's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%27s_formula).

Comment: Then we can ask more.  Suppose the equation is true on and interval in $\mathbb R$.  Or true on a set with a limit point.

Comment: @GEdgar: right, so I think we can bootstrap as follows: if the two Dirichlet series converge anywhere then they both converge and are holomorphic on some half-plane $\{ \text{Re}(s) > r \}$. Then if they agree on a subset of this half-plane with a limit point we can apply the identity theorem to conclude that they agree on the entire half-plane, then run the above argument.